# How to search for customers and be able to update them?

Tags: c#

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r376M.png)Hello I am trying to build an inventory application and need to be able to search for customers and be able to update them. I was able to add customers to the table and display them in the datagridview but i can't figure out how to search for a customer. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3CH8.png)

Answer (score 1):

First Try to check if your reader has rows(if you are getting any records with your query),

```
     if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            custTx.text = reader.GetString(0);
            custTx.text = reader.GetString(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //MessageBox
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: it seems like the query is not returning any records :(

Comment: @Teddy, if my comment helped you to figure out, kindly mark as an answer:-)